# http://hostname:5000/ runs on the machine but not remotely?

Tags: windows, http, firewall, windows-server

I created a console application (Asp.Net core Kestrel) which host a web site and copied it to a Windows Server. Browsing http://hostname:5000/ locally on the server works. However, it got `This site can’t be reachedu _hostname_ refused to connect.` when browsing the site on another machine.

I already created an inbound firewall rule.

[image: Firewall]
[image: Program]

I tried create a website in IIS on the server with port 5009. And the website can be remotely accessed.

Comment: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/sep/28/external-network-access-to-kestrel-and-iis-express-in-aspnet-core  "The issue is that the default binding that Kestrel uses, binds explicitly to localhost. A localhost bound IP won't expose to the external network, so even though you might be able to access other ports on the VM over the network - like IIS running on port 80 - accessing of http://<WindowsVmIp>:5000/ is not supported without some configuration changes."

Comment: Thanks. I tried to specify the url with host name. It gets some new error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59185648/kestrel-an-anonymous-request-was-received-in-between-authentication-handshake-r