# Kestrel: An anonymous request was received in between authentication handshake requests?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I created an Kestrel Asp.Net core application and tried to host it on a Windows Server (`server1`). I launch the application using

Browsing http://server1:8008 on server1 works without any error.

However, when browsing http://server1:8008 on a remote machine, it gets the following error?

```
PS C:\Websites\Portal> .\Blazor.exe --urls http://server1:8008
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://[::]:8008
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Websites\Portal
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
      Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler[5]
      An exception occurred while processing the authentication request.
System.InvalidOperationException: An anonymous request was received in between authentication handshake requests.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidOperationException: An anonymous request was received in between authentication handshake requests.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware midd
leware, HttpContext context, Task task)
```

Comment: 1. According to this [test](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/8c02467b4a218df3b1b0a69bceb50f5b64f482b1/src/Security/Authentication/Negotiate/test/Negotiate.Test/NegotiateHandlerTests.cs#L98), it must throw if you send another request without Authorization header **after** the previous request has started the authentication but **before** the authentication has finished during one connection.

Comment: 2. (too long to be pasted into one single comment): See also the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/8c02467b4a218df3b1b0a69bceb50f5b64f482b1/src/Security/Authentication/Negotiate/src/NegotiateHandler.cs#L96-L101). So that's a behavior by design.

Comment: Why only browsing on the remote machine doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

A bit old, but, the correction for this....

You need to setup SPNs for your application. Once the proper SPN is in place, the issue should go away.